# How to take 5 elements of JsArray in Scala?

Tags: json, scala

The below code compiles, but throws an error: `Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError:[{"id":6430758,"name":...] (of class play.api.libs.json.JsArray)`. How can I read JSON for the given link by taking the `items` list in it and only 5 elements?

```
import play.api.libs.json._

  def getProjects: List[Map[String, Any]] = {
    val iter = getJSON("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=scala")
    val json: JsValue = Json.parse(iter.get mkString "\n")
    val projects = (json \ "items") match {
      case l: List[Map[String, Any]] => l take 5
    }
    projects
  }

  def getJSON(url: String): Try[Iterator[String]] =
    Try(Source.fromURL(url).getLines) recover {
      case e: FileNotFoundException =>
        throw new AppException(s"Requested page does not exist: ${e.getMessage}.")
      case e: MalformedURLException =>
        throw new AppException(s"Please make sure to enter a valid URL: ${e.getMessage}.")
      case _ => throw new AppException("An unexpected error has occurred.")
    }
```

Comment: the type of `(json \ "items")` is JsArray

Comment: @ipoteka it's JsValue, not JsArray.

Comment: @Ryan He can easily match against JsArray, not List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Play, you should work within its `JsValue` abstraction rather than jumping out to a `Map[String, Any]`.

The reason your match is failing is because `json \ "items"` *isn't* a `Map[String, Any]`, it's a `JsValue`.  Ideally, you know the structure of your JSON (what your schema for project is) and you can deserialize to that:

```
case class Project(id: Long, name: String, ...)

object Project {
  implicit val fmt = Json.format[Project]
}

val projects = WS.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=scala").map { response =>
  response.json.validate[Map[String, Project]].map(_ take 5)
}
```

That leaves you with a `Future[JsResult[Map[String, Project]]]`.  The outer type is `Future` because the operation is inherently asynchronous, `JsResult` will be either a `JsSuccess` with your `Map[String, Project]` or a `JsError` containing the reason(s) your JSON couldn't be validated.

Answer (score 2):

It feels quick and dirty, but if that's really what you're wanting to do then you can try:

```
val listOfMaps: Seq[Map[String, String]] =
    (res1 \ "items").as[JsArray].value.map { jsobj =>
        jsobj.as[JsObject].value.map { case (key, value) =>
            key -> value.toString
        }
    }.take(5)
```

A better option would be to create a case class with they keys and types that you are expecting and write a Reads to parse the Json to that case class. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators. Then you would have a list of your case class and you can easily take 5 from there.